# Is a function restricted to a curve multi-variable?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, elementary-set-theory

If I define a function $f$ whose domain is {$(a,a),a∈R$} can this be described as multi-variable, the definition of a multi-variable function is a function of arity $2$ with domain defined such that it contains at least one non-empty open set, is my domain an open set in $R^2$? Or is $f$ not multi-variable?

Comment: $S:=\{(a,a): a \in \mathbb{R} \}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology because $(0,0) \in S$ but $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2<\varepsilon\} \not\subseteq S$ for any $\varepsilon>0$.

Comment: I propose a more convenient title for this question: Is such a function "multi-variable"?

Comment: A [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) is a function is a function.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I agree

Answer (score 5):

This is not about open sets. And whether or not a function is "multi-variable" is, without context, completely academic. Any "two-variable" function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ such as $f(x,y)=x^2+y$ can be realised also as a "single variable" function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$. It's just harder to describe what $f(\mathbf{x})$ is without coordinates. At the formal level, functions map elements of sets to elements of other sets. It is always taking in a single element - in the standard notations - but this element might have many "variables" within.

Whether or not a function is multi-variable is completely up to you. An example of where the apparent distinction between one or more variable real functions is important is when doing multivariable analysis: e.g. partial differentiation behaves differently to the univariate derivative. The distinction is here useful only because the quantities we are interested in can be very usefully coordinate-ised via $(x,y,z,\cdots)$. And yes, strictly speaking you could argue (say) that $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R\neq\Bbb R^3$ as a literal set equality, but the isomorphism there is so natural that most people use it without further comment.

Comment: How would you define $\mathbb{R}^2$ if not as $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ set theoretically? Your point works in cases like $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}\neq\mathbb{R}^3$, but I really can't see it in the case or $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @Lorago Whoops. I was thinking about examples like $\Bbb R^2\times\Bbb R\neq\Bbb R^3$

Answer (score 1):

Your domain is equivalent to the line $y=x$, going through the origin in $\mathbb R^2$. As a subset of $\mathbb R^2$, it contains no open sets. Consider a ball $B_0 :=B((0,0);r);r>0$ about  $(0,0)$. Informally, no points in $B_0$ , other than $(0,0)$ itself will be of the form $(a,a)$, as the line $y=x$ contains all such points. More rigorously, such ball will contain the point $(0,r/2)$; since $d((0,0),(0,r/2))=r/2<r$ . But since $r>0$, the point $(0,r/2)$ is not of the form $(a,a)$, and hence { $(a,a): a \in \mathbb R\}$ is not open in $\mathbb R^2$.